# How can I modify a list in a list without modifying the other lists?

Tags: python, list

I have a list made out of several lists (e.g. `lst = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`), and I created this list appending another list to it with a `for` loop:

```
for i in range(0, 3):
    lst.append([1, 2, 3])
```

Then I tried to modify one of those lists (`lst[0].remove(1)`).

But when I do that, all of the lists get modified, and the list looks like that: `[[2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3]]`

Is there any way I can modify the list so it looks like `[[2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`?

I also tried to use the `del` function, but I didn't seem to work.

Comment: @MattPitkin You provided enough info to constitute an answer, so please post it as actual answer and delete the comments - the code will be more readable, at least.

Comment: The code you have shown already does what you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you are actually creating the list in the way you state, then the removal of an item should work as expected. What I assume you you're actually doing is creating a list by appending the same list to it multiple times, i.e.,

```
sublist = [1, 2, 3]
mylist = []
for _ in range(3)
    mylist.append(sublist)
```

In this case the outer `mylist` just contains pointers/references to the *same* object, so if you modify one you modify them all.

Instead you need to make sure you append copies of the list, e.g.,

```py
sublist = [1, 2, 3]
mylist = []
for _ in range(3):
    mylist.append(list(sublist))  # using list creates a copy
```

Then you'll find that:

```
mylist[0].remove(1)
```

gives

```
print(mylist)
[[2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Note: calling your list `list` is not a good idea as is overwrites the built-in Python `list`.

P.S. - this is a common issue encountered by people starting out in Python, see, e.g., [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly) and many of the linked questions.

Answer (score 0):

this works as expected

```
li = []

for i in range(0, 3):
  li.append([1, 2, 3])

li[0].remove(1)

print(li)
```

Output:

```
[[2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: `list([1, 2, 3])` is a bit redundant. the `list` constructor is used in Matts answer because he only uses a reference to a list, so he must copy it. you use the literal syntax, so a new list is created in each loop anyways